# Solving non-linear recurernce relation

Tags: complexity-theory, analysis, recurrence

I want to solve analytically this relation :
`T[n] =1/n * T^2[n/2]+n`
We know n is a power of 2.

I know I can't use master theorem.
I tried to replace and replace till I get something.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1):

Proposing `T[n] = a*n` and substituting we have `a*n = 1/n*(a n)^2/4+a*n` and then `a = a^2/4+1` or `(a-2)^2 = 0` hence

`T[n] = 2*n`

is a solution.